# Regular expression for pages in Google Analytics that matches full words only

Tags: google-analytics, regular-expression

I am trying to create a regular expression to see all my landing pages in one search result.

This is what I have so far, but this regular expression  does not consider the `(\W|$))`, meaning that I receive results which that word is not the end of the string (I know I would need to add the beginning and ending `/` to be getting any meaningful data)

```
((\W|^)[Pp]rofessional(\W|$)|(\W|^)[Aa]dam(\W|$)|(\W|^)[Dd]unkey(\W|$)|(\W|^)[Aa]ny[Pp]ur(\W|$)|(\W|^)[Ee]nd(\W|$)|(\W|^)[fF]inal(\W|$))
```

I tried to follow the [Google's guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en) again to no avail:

```
(\W|^)([Pp]rojects|[Aa]wards|[Dd]ownload|[Aa]bout[Pp]ages|[Ee]xperts|[fF]orum)(\W|$)
```

Comment: Try to use this guideline https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your final regular expression.   You are missing a pipe between "about" and "pages". (Edit: this appears to be intentional as the page is named "AboutPages".)

Instead of `(\w|^`) and `(\W|$)` you could try `\b` which is "word boundary".   I plugged that into a regular expression tester and it seems to work well: http://regex101.com/r/tF1lZ4

```
\b([Pp]rojects|[Aa]wards|[Dd]ownload|[Aa]bout[Pp]ages|[Ee]xperts|[fF]orum)\b
```

Comment: Hi there eagle eyes Stephen, well I have unfortunately a landing page that actually is called AboutPages... But you were absolutely right with \b... with a minor modification it worked like a charm:

^/\b([Pp]rojects|[Aa]wards|[Dd]ownload|[Aa]bout[Pp]ages|[Ee]xperts|[fF]orum)\b$